Arbitrary product in the category of graded vector spaces
Is the category of graded vector spaces closed under arbitrary product?
I am a bit confused regarding this question. I can figure out that this category is closed under finite product in the following way: Let $V_\bullet = \oplus_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}V_k$  and $W_\bullet = \oplus_{l \in \mathbb{Z}} W_l$ be two graded vector space. Then $V_\bullet \otimes W_{\bullet} := \oplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\oplus_{k+l=n}V_{k} \otimes W_l$. Then similarly using induction we can construct any finite product in the category of graded vector spaces.
However, this method will not work when dealing with an arbitrary product. As the second summand (one with $k+l=n$) will then contain an infinite sum.
Please help me understand how to define arbitrary product in the category of graded vector spaces.

Edit
I apologize for not framing my question properly. The question I want to ask is the following:
In the category of vector spaces. The categorical product is given by the cartesian product. Therefore, the category of vector spaces is closed under arbitrary product.
Question: What is the categorical product in the category of graded vector spaces? And is this category closed under arbitrary product?

It looks like you're trying to define the tensor product of graded vector spaces, but your question asks about the ordinary (categorical) product...

Please do not answer in the comments, @QiaochuYuan.

@Shaun: are you deleting comments now that are not spam? That's ridiculous. I was yelled at by the moderators some months ago for answering questions that in their opinion weren't sufficiently high-quality so I shifted towards commenting by default. Isn't it better for the OP to have useful information rather than to not have it?

@QiaochuYuan https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

The categorical product in the category of graded vector spaces is pointwise, so if $V_{\bullet}$ and $W_{\bullet}$ are two graded vector spaces their categorical product is
$$(V \times W)_i = V_i \times W_i$$
and the same is true for the product of arbitrarily many graded vector spaces.
This is not the operation you discuss in the first half of your question, which is the tensor product. There's no issue with taking infinite direct sums, and the tensor product is also defined for arbitrarily many graded vector spaces, although in my experience infinite tensor products aren't really used for anything.
So it sounds to me like you are confused about the difference between the categorical product and the tensor product (and about the difference between infinite direct sums and infinite sums).

One thing to add is that the categorical product of a collection of graded vector spaces (which Qiaochu correctly describes) is not formed by taking the product of the underlying total spaces and then somehow putting a grading on that. Instead, take the product at the level of grade-$n$ components for each $n$; then you can form a total space from that. The description of a graded vector space as a single vector space equipped with a grading, while not incorrect, masks how one should form products.
